# Cannot find module 'gulp'

Tags: module, gulp, ionic3, find

Greetings!
Please i get this error when running ionic serve

`Error: Cannot find module 'gulp'`
I don't know were the problem is.

I installed the latest version of gulp and yet the error is still there.

After running ionic serve, this is the error it shows

```
[v1] Error: Cannot find module 'gulp'
[v1]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
[v1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
[v1]     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
[v1]     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
[v1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gideon/Documents/IONIC/shoppingcart2/ionic-firebase-shopping-cart-master(copy)(copy)/gulpfile.js:1:74)
[v1]     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
[v1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
[v1]     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
[v1]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
[v1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Please any solution to this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install gulp both globally and locally?  See instructions at https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start